# When is FileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents) called?

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I have a FileAppender, and usually the events are loggend in through the method Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) so a single event per time.I do have a question, in which cases the method Append(LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents)  is called? I understand that is when there is an array of events to log, but my question is, how can i simulate the case of an array of events? what has to happen in order that the FileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents) is called ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right: if you use "just" a FileAppender each event is logged via the Append(LoggingEvent) method.

The other method call is fired when you are buffering events via, for example, the [BufferingForwardingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender.html): it will keep events in memory until some conditions are met, then it will call Append(LoggingEvent[]) on its inner appenders.